# Celerybeat occasionally missing tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

We have a setup of Celery (+Celerybeat) with a RabbitMQ backend running scheduled and unscheduled tasks.  I've noticed that I occasionally miss/drop an occurrence of a scheduled task.  Everything continues to work correctly, and the task continues to run on its next scheduled due time, but it just looks like some of the runs are disappearing.  Example of the log for a task that's supposed to run every 10 minutes:

```
[2013-03-04 02:28:41,630: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[8e442788-9501-4043-9708-0acc43b1e5c0] succeeded in 2.83057904243s: None
[2013-03-04 02:38:41,611: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[97b2daf0-100c-4e63-8a03-833fccd7c7fe] succeeded in 2.7966811657s: None
[2013-03-04 02:48:41,398: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[d58e0270-3b9d-448e-a95a-5f6865a85c00] succeeded in 2.61804389954s: None
[2013-03-04 02:59:04,136: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[925d63e8-6669-4ffb-8ff1-a79dac28689e] succeeded in 2.69637179375s: None
[2013-03-04 03:19:04,066: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[cb903ba2-f9cc-475b-8275-9af400e11443] succeeded in 2.59652400017s: None
[2013-03-04 03:29:06,002: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[b9bc019b-a44e-430f-9cdb-d1b919d9cf08] succeeded in 0.994740962982s: None
[2013-03-04 03:48:41,414: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[8ec75918-0127-411c-b1fa-a338129259e7] succeeded in 2.6219689846s: None
[2013-03-04 03:58:40,936: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[bbcdeaf3-0b83-440e-b9c8-08ed67b17e27] succeeded in 2.1441078186s: None
[2013-03-04 04:08:41,323: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[f42ce313-a200-4bdd-9b47-c37f4a7da003] succeeded in 2.53811717033s: None
[2013-03-04 04:29:04,103: INFO/MainProcess] Task my.task.name[526427fd-a609-4abd-ab42-cae0b0f267b6] succeeded in 2.59499788284s: None
```

You can see that the 3:08 run is missing, as is the 3:38 and 4:08.

My question is: how can I *troubleshoot* this issue?  I assume nobody can provide me with a solution based on this data, but perhaps someone can suggest a method that will determine what could be causing this.

More info about our setup that might help:

- We are running Django 1.2.7, Celery 2.4.6, and django-celery 2.4.2.
- We are running RabbitMQ 3.0.2-1.
- We have two servers running Celeryd (against the same RabbitMQ server).  Both are running celeryd_multi since we have two separate queues.  Only one runs celerybeat, of course.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm hitting the same issue and it is maddening.

Comment: Same here, getting the same problem. Getting logs from beat indicating that it actually misses scheduling tasks sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running celerybeat with -l DEBUG?

It will show tasks being received by the queue and lots of other information which might provide clues as to why the tasks aren't being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not too late to answer the question,let's back to the answer, We were also facing this issue, after wasting hours we identified that using less number of workers causing this issue. We **increased the workers** and issue was resolved.

Comment: Please how does one increase the number of workers?

Comment: @inyangkpongette Increase worker in celery system-d service.